# windsor dependency problem

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I've got:

```
public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    public ServiceA(IServiceB serv){...}
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
}
```

Both registered as singletons.

Now when I do:

```
..Container.Resolve<IServiceB>()
```

I would like to make sure that `IServiceA` has also been resolved. It comes to making somekind of dependecy between these services although don't know how to do that.

EDIT:

What I Expect is to do something like:

```
var B = ..Container.Resolve<IServiceB>(); 
//Make sure IServiceA has been resolved
B.SomeFunction();
```

`B.SomeFunction()` needs `IServiceA` to be resolved for the reason of doing some stuff `Event Based`

NOTE: I dont resolve IServiceB straight in the code, but through a different classes constructor.

Comment: Provide more detail as to why you'd expect it to work, and what breaks because it isn't working.  What dependency does `IServiceB` have on `IServiceA`?  Your current signatures suggest there is no dependency (in that direction).  This might help people suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

IServiceB has no dependency on IServiceA, though the opposite is true.  It will resolve IServiceB if you ask for IServiceA.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the resolving options in constructors as how I wrote them is the way I need them

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, what you're asking.  If you need both IServiceA and IServiceB resolved at the same time, call .Resolve on IServiceA or fix the code dependencies.